# Debezium : Data deleted from MySQL reappearing in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I've used Debezium for Mysql -> Elasticsearch CDC.
Now, the issue is that when I delete data from MySQL, it still reappears in Elasticsearch, even if data is no longer present in MySQL DB. UPDATE and INSERT works fine, but DELETE isn't.
Also, I did the following:

- 1. Delete data in MySQL
- 2. Delete Elasticsearch Index and ES Kafka Sink
- 3. Create a new connector for ES in Kakfa

Now, the weird part is that all of my deleted data reappers here as well! When I check ES data before step (3), data wasn't there. But afterwards, this behaviour is observed.

Please help me fix this issue!

MySQL config :

```
 "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval": "true",
    "database.user": "cdc-reader",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "X.X.X.X:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.mysql",
    "database.server.name": "data_test",
    "schema.include.list": "data_test",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "tombstones.on.delete": "true",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "database.hostname": "X.X.X.X",
    "database.password": "xxxxx",
    "name": "slave_test",
    "database.history.skip.unparseable.ddl": "true",
    "table.include.list": "search_ai.*"
  },
```

Elasticsearch config:

```
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "delete",
    "transforms.extractKey.field": "ID",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "search_ai.search_ai.slave_data",
    "transforms.InsertKey.fields": "ID",
    "transforms": "unwrap,key,InsertKey,extractKey",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "transforms.extractKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.key.field": "ID",
    "transforms.key.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "name": "esd_2",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "connection.url": "http://X.X.X.X:9200",
    "transforms.InsertKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Debezium is reading the transaction log, not the source table, so the inserts and updates are always going to be read first, causing inserts and doc updates in Elasticsearch...

Secondly, did you create the sink connector with a new name or different one?

- If the same one, the original consumer group offsets would not have changed, causing the consumer group to pickup at the offsets before you deleted the original connector
- if a new name, and depending on the auto.offset.reset value of the sink connector consumer, you could be consuming the Debezium topic from the beginning, and causing data to get re-inserted into Elasticsearch, as mentioned. You need to check if your Mysql delete events are actually getting produced/consumed as tombstone values to cause deletes in Elasticsearch

Comment: I've created the second connector with a new name.
I've set "tombstones.on.delete" to "true" for MySQL and "behavior.on.null.values": "delete"in ES sink. Would this be enough?
Also, in Kafka messages, I am getting 
before : {"ID":1,....}
after:null 
op : 'd' 
But still, delete isn't working

Comment: Are you sure the `ExtractNewRecordState` transform is only returning the `after` value? Otherwise, that record alone won't cause deletes. You can use FileStreamSink to test you're getting the expected connector output

Comment: It is returning both before and after value with after set to null as "after":null

Comment: Right. And the entire Kafka record needs to be (ID,null) for you to be able to delete the document ID in Elasticsearch, so keep debugging the transform configs. For example, maybe you want to set drop.tombstones to false https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/event-flattening.html#configuration-options

Comment: Thanks for the help. Found out that PK wasn't set for all of my MySQL tables. And that caused null values in between.